# surefire-plugin does not respect threadCount parameter

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

Since several days, I tried to see where is my mistake in my configuration to run in parallel my Selenium tests.

I have a Selenium Grid with 2 nodes. 
In my pom.xml, I have set surefire to run 2 by 2 the methods of my tests with a particular category then other tests.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>methods</parallel>
                        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>

                        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                        <groups>
                            com.something.categories.Safe,
                            com.something.categories.Parallel
                        </groups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>no-safe</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludedGroups>
                            com.something.categories.Safe,
                            com.something.Parallel
                        </excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I launch my test *mvn clean test -Dtest='TestAwesome'* all the tests contains in TestAwesome are launched in the same time (I see more than 2 browsers opended), and so does not respect my threadCount value.

I'm missing something?

**Edition after answer**
Here my partial pom.xml to solve my issue

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>all</parallel>
                        <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
                        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <browser>${browser}</browser>
                            <screenshotDirectory>${project.build.directory}/screenshots</screenshotDirectory>
                            <gridURL>${seleniumGridURL}</gridURL>
                            <env>${env}</env>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <groups>${groups}</groups>
                        <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: What is the execution with id=no-safe used for?  If you comment out that execution do you see the same behavior?

Comment: I've split the test execution in two parts. The first one should run the tests that can be parallelize. The second part should run the remaining test.
I've tried to remove this last one, but the result is still the same. I even tried without execution section to have an easiest case, same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a modern-enough version of surefire, you might wanna try the *threadCountMethods* parameter instead of threadCount in combination with *useUnlimitedThreads* = true, even though it seems counter-intuitive.

[surefire jUnit examples](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html):

> As of Surefire 2.7, no additional dependencies are needed to use the full set of options with parallel. As of Surefire 2.16, new thread-count attributes are introduced, namely threadCountSuites, threadCountClasses and **threadCountMethods**.

[Fork options and parallel execution](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html):

> As an example with an unlimited number of threads, there is maximum of three concurrent threads to execute suites: parallel = all, useUnlimitedThreads = true, threadCountSuites = 3.

Comment: Thank you @Carsten. _useUnlimitedThreads = true_ solved my issue. Indeed, it's not obvious.
I will update my question with my finale pom.xml.