# How do I get Maven Surefire to run all classes and tests?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Java JUnit Selenium test framework running some tests.  There are two classes with two tests each.

I have maven surefire configured like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>100</threadCount>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </configuration>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</plugin>
```

I'd like it to run 4 tests simultaneously, but no matter what combination of `threadCount`, `parallel` and `fork` settings I use, I can only seem to get 1 class worth of test cases to run at a time.  It seems like this should work, can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: i think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970907/concurrent-junit-testing

Comment: Use `threadCountMethods` & set `useUnlimitedThreads` to true & `parallel` to all (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31515811/4072371)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run suites in parallel or methods or tests in parallel?

The only working solution that I found for running Suites in parallel is setting

```
<property>
   <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
   <value>8</value>
</property>
```

in the pom.xml. Every other combination did not work as I needed the tests to run on same JVM, not start forked processes.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following configuration for surefire `v2.20.1` in maven `v3.5.0`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
        <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>2</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I believe this is working as our test suite is a lot quicker than it used to be and windows reports the running processes as largely increased specifically when surefire is running.

Answer (score 0):

Probably 1 year too late for you, but just in case it can help someone.

Using parallel=methods like you did will launch all tests (methods) at a time, but 1 class at a time (sequential).  So in your example, 2 classes having 2 tests, you will have all tests of of ClassA to execute, then all tests of ClassB.

If you were to use parallel=classes, then all the classes would launch at the same time, but running 1 test (method) at a time (sequential). So in your example, 2 classes having 2 tests, you will have Test1 of ClassA and Test1 of ClassB to start in parallel, and then Test2 of ClassA and Test2 of ClassB to execute afterward.

Since you want all 4 tests to execute in parallel, then use parallel=all.
Both methods and classes will execute in parallel.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>all</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Note : alternatively, you may want to remove the < configuration > block and set them as parameters in your mvn command line.
Ex: mvn clean test -Dparallel=all -DthreadCount=10

Regards,